# error with compilation of nr.f90

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I need to use MRQMIN subroutine in my Fortran 90 code. Inside this subroutine there are some other modules `nrtype.90`, `nrutil.f90` and `nr.f90`. I'm compiling  all these modules and my own code with these commands

```
ifort -c nrtype.90  
ifort -c nrutil.f90  
ifort -c nr.f90    
ifort test.f90 nrtype.o nrutil.o nr.o -o test
```

but I'm receiving this error

```
/tmp/ifortcx4Tb3.o: In function `mrqmin_IP_mrqmin_private_':  
   test.f90:(.text+0x4041): undefined reference to `gaussj_'  
   test.f90:(.text+0x4896): undefined reference to `covsrt_'     
   test.f90:(.text+0x48a5): undefined reference to `covsrt_'
```

am I missing some thing here during the compilation?

Comment: I have both functions gaussj & covsrt in both mrqmin subroutine and nr.f90. MRQMIN is using these three module and nr.f90 is using nrtype.f90 .I have "use" command in MRQMIN and nr.f90 .  But I don't have the function `mrqmin_IP_mrqmin_private_'

Comment: So the functions `gaussj` and `covsrt`, and the subroutine `mrqmin` are in the same module in the file `nr.f90`?

Comment: no, mrqmin is subroutine I'm using in my main code "test.f90" and all the other modules are use by mrqmin                                         http://users.polytech.unice.fr/~dedale/cours/maths_physique_chimie/mathematiques/Numerical_Recipes/cornell_only/fortran.210/f90/recipes/mrqmin.f90                                                         but these two functions are used with both nr.f90 and mrqmin

Answer (score 3):

`nr.f90` only provides the *interfaces* to the subroutines, not the subroutines themselves.

You have to compile `gaussj.f90` and `covsrt.f90` separately and specify them as well (I tried it for `gfortran` but it should work with `ifort` as well):

```
gfortran -c gaussj.f90
gfortran -c covsrt.f90
gfortran test.f90 mrqmin.o nr.o nrtype.o nrutil.o gaussj.o covsrt.o
```

Comment: thanks a lot it worked for gaussj.f90 but would you please send me the link which I can download covsrt.f90 too? I can't find it

Comment: I used the link you provided (it's in the same directory);-)